# Automatically align y-axis text and grid lines to bottom and top of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Our company chart layout is based on Excel. In Excel by default the y-axis text and grid lines start at the bottom and end at the top of the chart. Using R and ggplot2 the default behavior seems that only labels which are between the min and max of the data are shown.

Manually, I would just use limits as in the example below to achieve the desired outcome. However, is there a way to achieve this behavior automatically? Doing it manually for each chart is not an option as we have hundreds of charts where the data changes over time.

```
library( ggplot2 )

# transform data to make the problem more obvious
df <- cars
df$speed  <- df$speed + 4

# default ggplot behaviour: y-axis grid lines and ticks are placed where they fit best
ggplot( df, aes( x = dist, y = speed ) ) + 
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle( "Default behavior: y-axis grid lines and text inside data-range" ) +
  scale_y_continuous( expand = c( 0, 0 ) ) +
  theme( panel.background    = element_rect( fill   = "white" ),
         panel.border        = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.major.y  = element_line( colour = "#d9d9d9",
                                             size   = 0.001 ),
         axis.ticks.x        = ggplot2::element_line( color = "#d9d9d9" ),
         axis.ticks.y        = ggplot2::element_blank() )

# desired outcome: y-axis text and grid lines start at bottom and end at top (achieved with expand and limits)
ggplot( df, aes( x = dist, y = speed ) ) + 
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle( "Disired outcome: y-axis grid lines and text at bottom and top" ) +
  scale_y_continuous( expand = c( 0, 0 ), 
                      limits = c( 5, 30 ) ) +
  theme( panel.background    = element_rect( fill   = "white" ),
         panel.border        = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.major.y  = element_line( colour = "#d9d9d9",
                                             size   = 0.001 ),
         axis.ticks.x        = ggplot2::element_line( color = "#d9d9d9" ),
         axis.ticks.y        = ggplot2::element_blank() )
```

Default ggplot2 behavior: note that y-axis text and grid-lines are not aligned to bottom and top of the chart

[image: Default ggplot2 behavior: note that y-axis text and grid-lines are not aligned to bottom and top of the chart]

Desired outcome: y-axis text and grid-lines are at the bottom and top of the chart (values 5 and 30)

[image: Desired outcome: y-axis text and grid-lines are at the bottom and top of the chart (values 5 and 30)]

Comment: As a side note there is a theme excel XD : https://rdrr.io/cran/ggthemes/man/theme_excel_new.html

Comment: @QAsena thanks. I know that an Excel theme is already implemented in R. However, this does not solve my problem as the position of grid-lines is not changed. Furthermore, as our layout slightly deviates from theme_excel_new() I created my own theme. The code above only shows a small part of this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `limits` argument to a scale can accept a function that will be applied to the range of the data, we can make a function that sets the limits automatically to nicer numbers. Here is an example function that you could use, but I haven't tested this for all possible cases.

```r
library( ggplot2 )

# transform data to make the problem more obvious
df <- cars
df$speed  <- df$speed + 4

nicelimits <- function(x) {
  # x is the range of the data
  # get breaks under default breaks behaviour (breaks are not known in advance)
  breaks <- scales::extended_breaks()(x)
  # Take the difference between breaks (should be constant)
  width  <- diff(breaks)[1]
  # Do something like `floor()`, but with `width`-units
  start <- (x[1] %/% width) * width
  # Do something like `ceiling()`, but with `width`-units
  end <- (c(x[2] %/% width) + 1) * width
  c(start, end)
}


ggplot( df, aes( x = dist, y = speed ) ) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous( expand = c( 0, 0 ),
                      limits = nicelimits) +
  theme( panel.background    = element_rect( fill   = "white" ),
         panel.border        = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.major.y  = element_line( colour = "#d9d9d9",
                                             size   = 0.001 ),
         axis.ticks.x        = ggplot2::element_line( color = "#d9d9d9" ),
         axis.ticks.y        = ggplot2::element_blank() )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

EDIT: As @stefan in the comment pointed out, this would also make nice limits and is less custom code:

```r
nicelimits <- function(x) {
  range(scales::extended_breaks(only.loose = TRUE)(x))
}
```

A difference I noticed is that the first function will extend the upper limit by `+ width` if the upper limit is at a break, whereas the latter function will return the natural upper limit in this case.

Comment: Nice job. As I just figured out you can pass extended_breaks the argument `only.loose=TRUE` which automatically gives extreme labels outside of the data range, i.e. one can set the limits via `range(scales::extended_breaks(only.loose = TRUE)(x))`

Comment: Thanks @stefan, I didn't know about this argument and that would indeed simplify the function by a lot! I'll edit the answer to include that option.

Comment: Yep, neither did I. (:  Actually it's an argument of the underlying labeling::extended. Best S.

Comment: @teunbrand and @stefan thanks a lot! I didn't know that the `limits` argument accepts a function.

Comment: I just figured out that for the second approach to work properly also the `breaks` argument of `scale_y_continuous` needs to be defined: `breaks = scales::extended_breaks( only.loose = TRUE )`. Otherwise breaks and limits do not always fit together.